# How can I setup Catalina Home for my specific tomcat instance in Mac?

Tags: java, tomcat

I download tomcat to:

```
Macintosh HD ▸ Users ▸ koraytugay ▸ Applications ▸ apache-tomcat-7.0.55
```

And I also copied the whole folder (except the bin folder) to:

```
Macintosh HD ▸ Users ▸ koraytugay ▸ Applications ▸ tomcatinstance ▸ myshopcart
```

I have also copied a .war file to the second location **/webapps** folder.

What I want to achieve is, I want that tomcat is started from where the first folder is but configuration is read from the second one.

What I have tried is, I copied catalina.sh to second location and added this line:

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/Users/koraytugay/Applications/tomcatinstance/myshopcart
```

but this did not work.. I called **catalina.sh** from the second location but I got:

```
Cannot find /Users/koraytugay/Applications/tomcatinstance/myshopcart/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set `CATALINA_BASE` for each instance and `CATALINA_HOME` for binary distribution, for example:

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/Users/koraytugay/Applications/tomcatinstance
export CATALINA_BASE=/Users/koraytugay/Applications/tomcatinstance/myshopcart
```

See also: [Running Multiple Tomcat Instances on One Server](http://java.dzone.com/articles/running-multiple-tomcat)